# unable to run production build command for android in ionic cordova application

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I run **ionic cordova build android --prod --release** command in cmd prompt, I'm getting the below error. I also tried running **ionic cordova build android --prod --release --aot=false**

**Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'NgxDynamicTemplateModule',function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppModule in /src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /src/app/app.module.ts**

Comment: which ersion of ionic/cordova are you using?

Comment: ionic 3.20.0 and cordova 8.0.0

Comment: DId you see that thread? https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/is-it-possible-to-do-a-production-build-without-aot-and-will-it-be-possible-using-ionic-angular-4/119050/5 From one of replies (Jan 23), it looks like you cannot disable aot if building with --prod

Comment: I just tried running that command with aot=false. But the main issue is , I'm unable to build production release of my app with dynamic template module.

Comment: Yeah but from what that link indicates, you cannot disable aot when building with prod flag. And that lib you are using does  not support aot